# predicate function in map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have been studying `purrr` family functions recently and while I was reading the documentation of `map_if` I came across an alternative definition form for `.p` argument aka. predicate function that I could not understand. It say:

> "Alternatively, if the elements of .x are themselves lists of objects,
> a string indicating the name of a logical element in the inner lists"

I was wondering if someone could tell me what it means and how I can go about using it while I deal with a list whose elements are also lists. Something like this:

```
x <- list(a = list(foo = 1:2, bar = 3:4), b = list(baz = 5:6))
```

A simple example would be much appreciated as I've done some research and could not find any indication of it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I couldn't find any example either where a string is passed/returned in the predicate function. All of them return a logical value only.

Comment: @RonakShah you are right, I could realize what it means by "a string indicating the name of a logical element ...". I guess I may reach out to the Author. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not fully sure what actually you want to understand, but taking the case of list of lists, we need to consider that here only `map_if` is available and `pmap_if` is not available.  Let's take another list of lists than you have suggested.

```
x <- list(a = list(foo = 1:2, bar = 3:4), b = list(baz = 5:6), c = list(bird = 7:10))
```

Now `map_if` applies `.f` wherever `.p` is `T`.  So if we want to take mean of all odd indexed lists in list x, we have to actually  use nested `map` again.

see

```
map_if(x, as.logical(seq_along(x) %% 2) , ~map(.x, ~mean(.x)))

$a
$a$foo
[1] 1.5

$a$bar
[1] 3.5


$b
$b$baz
[1] 5 6


$c
$c$bird
[1] 8.5
```

we may also other predicate functions in `.p`.  The below example produces same output.

```
map_if(x, names(x) %in% c("a", "c") , ~map(.x, ~mean(.x)))
```

Or if let's say `x` is named something like this

```
x <- list(val1 = list(foo = 1:2, bar = 3:4), ind1 = list(baz = 5:6), val2 = list(bird = 7:10))
```

then below syntax will produce similar results

```
map_if(x, str_detect(names(x), "val") , ~map(.x, ~mean(.x)))
```

I hope this is somewhat near to you may want to understand.

P.S. You can give [it](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html) a read too.

Comment: Dear Anil, thank you for your explanation. The reason I asked this question back then was I couldn't find an example for this phrase that I found in documentation for `.p` which says ` a string indicating the name of a logical element in the inner lists` . I have already read advanced R but this is a very rare case that I could not find any example for. I'm not sure it is common or useful that much at all but back then it caught my attention.

Comment: I got your point actually after I posted the answer.  If you find an example or explanation do tag me. If you suggest I may delete this answer as it is not actually answering your query.  Meanwhile I am also looking for its explanation.

Comment: No it's a very good explanation. Let it stay here as it covers some very good example regarding the application of `map_if` function that also might help people in the future. But if I found anything I will share it with you as we have done in the past couple of days about these stuff. That phrase in the documentation is a bit ambiguous to me but I hope we will find a proper example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to refer to an inner variable name with a `TRUE`/`FALSE` value. Here is the basic example I created to test it.

Create a list where the inner list has boolean values for one variable:

```
A <- list(foo=list(x=1, y=TRUE), bar=list(x=2, y=FALSE))
```

Reference the boolean variable (`y`) as the `.p` predicate by passing a string with the variable name:

```
map_if(A, "y", as.character)

$foo
[1] "1"    "TRUE"

$bar
$bar$x
[1] 2

$bar$y
[1] FALSE
```

So, it only modified the `foo` variable since `y` was `TRUE` and `bar` wasn't altered since `y` was `FALSE`.